# D operator method

Tags: differential-operators

Verify that $y=x^2-6$ is a solution of 
$$y''+y'-2y=14+2x-2x^2$$
I have tried like this:
$$\begin{align}
P.I. &=\frac{14+2x-2x^2}{D^2+D-2}\\
& =\frac{-2(x^2-x-7)}{-2\left(1-\frac{D^2+D}{2}\right)}\\
& =x^2-x-7\left(1-\frac{D^2+D}{2}\right)^{-1}\\
& =x^2-x-7+\frac{2+2x-1}{2}\\
& =\frac{2x^2-13}{2}
\end{align}$$
I can't find where is my fault, please help

Comment: Why don't you just plug in $y$ to the lhs?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}(D^2+D-2)(y)&=(D^2+D-2)(x^2-6)\\&=
D^2(x^2-6)+D(x^2-6)-2(x^2-6)\\&=
2+2x-2x^2+12\\&=
14+2x-2x^2
\end{align}

Comment: You're right, this is a short cut method